# I can't pass the other page with Flutter onPress

Tags: dart, flutter

**I want to go to the other page when I clicked with the code on the press, but it doesn't work.**

```
 DialogButton(
      onPressed: () => FirstTab(),
      color: Color(0xff78328a),
      child: Text(
        "DAÜ'ye / To EMU",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: please give more information: which library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your `onPressed` method into this :

```
  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstTab()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use `Navigator.push` in order to move to next page like this in your `onPressed`

```
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return new PageName();
                        }));
```